# Android App Crashes After Opening Cemara Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, android-fragments, layout-inflater

In my Android application users can choose to select an image from phone gallery or take a picture with camera. But i realized that Android OS turning off my application after users choose the "take a picture" option(probably because of the low memory) and open the device camera. After users take a picture and click save button, the OS try to open my application again but i am facing with below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hms.socialsteps/com.hms.socialsteps.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in com.hms.socialsteps:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #21 in com.hms.socialsteps:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #21 in com.hms.socialsteps:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3526)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3665)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:151)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2228)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7888)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:512)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:998)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in com.hms.socialsteps:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #21 in com.hms.socialsteps:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #21 in com.hms.socialsteps:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in com.hms.socialsteps:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #21 in com.hms.socialsteps:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21 in com.hms.socialsteps:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #21: Duplicate id 0x7f0a01d9, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:117)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:227)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:45)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:39)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.ui.MainActivity$special$$inlined$viewBinding$1.invoke(ActivityViewBindingDelegate.kt:11)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.ui.MainActivity$special$$inlined$viewBinding$1.invoke(ActivityViewBindingDelegate.kt:8)
        at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.ui.MainActivity.getBinding(MainActivity.kt:31)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.ui.MainActivity.hideBottomNavigation(MainActivity.kt:72)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.ui.base.BaseFragment.onAttach(BaseFragment.kt:25)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.ui.activitydetails.Hilt_ActivityDetailsFragment.onAttach(Hilt_ActivityDetailsFragment.java:47)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:3063)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.attach(FragmentStateManager.java:464)
2023-04-18 19:37:10.444 8825-8825/com.hms.socialsteps E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:254)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1424)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2968)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2875)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1990)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1965)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.kt:169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3090)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:227)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:45)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:39)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.ui.MainActivity$special$$inlined$viewBinding$1.invoke(ActivityViewBindingDelegate.kt:11)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.ui.MainActivity$special$$inlined$viewBinding$1.invoke(ActivityViewBindingDelegate.kt:8)
        at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.ui.MainActivity.getBinding(MainActivity.kt:31)
        at com.hms.socialsteps.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7967)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7956)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3497)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3665)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:151)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2228)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7888)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:512)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:998)
```

I found the code that causing this problem, that code is inside the BaseFragment's onAttach method like below:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        baseContext = context
        if (!isBottomNavBarVisible){
            (activity as MainActivity).hideBottomNavigation()
        }
    }
```

When i remove this code part, app is not crashing. Can anyone help me to solve this inflating problem ? What could be the reson for this error ?

My other related classses:
MainActivity.kt

```
package com.hms.socialsteps.ui

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TAG = "MainActivity"

    private val binding by viewBinding(ActivityMainBinding::inflate)
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()


    private lateinit var snackbar: Snackbar


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(binding.root)

            getToken()

            val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

            val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
            navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

            observeNetworkStatus()
    }
    private fun observeNetworkStatus(){
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.root,
            "There is no internet connection!",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)

        viewModel.networkMonitor.observe(this){ connection ->
            if (!connection){
                snackbar.show()
            }else{
                snackbar.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

    fun showBottomNavigation()
    {
        binding.navView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    fun hideBottomNavigation()
    {
        binding.navView.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    fun getToken(){
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val appId = Constants.APP_ID

                val tokenScope = "HCM"
                val token = HmsInstanceId.getInstance(this@MainActivity).getToken(appId, tokenScope)
                Timber.tag(TAG).i( "get token:$token")

                // Check whether the token is null.
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
                    viewModel.setToken(token)
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                Timber.tag(TAG).e( "get token failed, $e")
            }
        }

        viewModel.tokenResult.observe(this){ result ->
            when(result){
                is Resource.Empty -> {}
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    Timber.tag(TAG).e( "getToken: ${result.message}")
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    Timber.tag(TAG).d( "getToken: Upsert token started.")
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    Timber.tag(TAG).d( "getToken: Token set.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BaseFragment.kt

```
package com.hms.socialsteps.ui.base

abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment {
    var baseContext: Context? = null

    constructor() : super()
    constructor(contentLayoutId: Int) : super(contentLayoutId)

    abstract val isBottomNavBarVisible: Boolean

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        baseContext = context
        if (!isBottomNavBarVisible){
            (activity as MainActivity).hideBottomNavigation()
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        if (isBottomNavBarVisible) {
            (activity as MainActivity).showBottomNavigation()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        with((requireActivity() as MainActivity)){
            if (isBottomNavBarVisible)
                showBottomNavigation()
            else
                hideBottomNavigation()
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Timber.v("LifeCycle", "${name()} onViewCreated")
    }


    private fun name(): String {
        return this.javaClass.simpleName
    }

    fun createMemberAlertDialog(memberDialogViewBinding: MemberSelectionViewBinding, context: Context):
    AlertDialog{
        val memberDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        memberDialogBuilder.setView(memberDialogViewBinding.root)
        val memberAlertDialog = memberDialogBuilder.create()
        memberAlertDialog.setCancelable(false)
        return memberAlertDialog
    }

    fun createInformationAlertDialog(informationViewBinding: GroupCreationViewBinding, context: Context):
            AlertDialog{
        val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        dialogBuilder.setView(informationViewBinding.root)
        val informationAlertDialog = dialogBuilder.create()
        informationAlertDialog.setCancelable(false)
        return informationAlertDialog
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ActivityDetailsFragment.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActivityDetailsFragment : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_activity_details) {
    private val binding: FragmentActivityDetailsBinding by viewBinding(
        FragmentActivityDetailsBinding::bind
    )

    private lateinit var dropDownMenu: PopupMenu
    private lateinit var menu: Menu

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private val postViewModel: PostViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private val activitiesViewModel by viewModels<ActivitiesViewModel>()

    private val editProfileViewModel by viewModels<EditProfileViewModel>()

    private var activityId: String? = null

    private lateinit var activity: Activities

    private var imageUri: Uri? = null

    private var croppedUri: Uri? = null

    private val values = ContentValues()

    @Inject
    lateinit var userPreference: UserPreference

    override val isBottomNavBarVisible: Boolean
        get() = false

    private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted ->
        if (isGranted) {
            takePhoto()
        }else {
            requireContext().showToastLong("Camera Permission not granted")
        }
    }

    private val pickMedia = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()){ uri ->
        if (uri != null) {
            startCrop(uri)
        } else {
            Timber.tag("PhotoPicker").d("No media selected")
        }
    }

    private val cameraLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                /*setActivityImage(imageUri)*/
                startCrop(imageUri!!)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    private val cropImage = registerForActivityResult(CropImageContract()) { result ->
        if (result.isSuccessful) {
            croppedUri = result.uriContent
            editProfileViewModel.setImageUri(croppedUri!!, activity, false)
            /*setActivityImage(uriContent)*/
        } else {
            // An error occurred.
            showSnackBarShort(result.error?.message ?: "Image crop failed!")
        }
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.parentConstraintLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

        activityId = arguments?.getString("activityId")

        initMenu()
        initData()
        initOnClickListeners()
        initObserver()
    }

    private fun initObserver() {
        editProfileViewModel.uploadResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Resource.Empty -> {}
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    hideProgressBar(binding.progressBar)
                    showSnackBarShort(result.message!!)
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    showProgressBar(binding.progressBar)
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgressBar(binding.progressBar)
                    showSnackBarShort("Image uploaded successfully.")
                    setActivityImage(croppedUri, null)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New asdasd")
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From asd Camera")
        imageUri = requireContext().contentResolver.insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values
        )
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
        cameraLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

    private fun startCrop(uri: Uri) {
        cropImage.launch(
            CropImageContractOptions(
                uri = uri,
                CropImageOptions(
                    guidelines = CropImageView.Guidelines.ON, fixAspectRatio = true,
                    outputRequestWidth = 800, outputRequestHeight = 800
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```